# How to solve: $\int\frac{\mathrm{e}^x}{\mathrm{e}^{2x}+3}\,\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

$${\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{\mathrm{e}^x}{\mathrm{e}^{2x}+3}\,\mathrm{d}x$$

I tried substituting $u= e^x$, $du = e^x dx$, and so I end up with:

$${\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{1}{\mathrm{u}^{2}+3}\,\mathrm{d}u$$

This looks like the derivative $\arctan(x)$, but I have a $3$ instead of a $1$. How can I solve this integral?

Comment: Now let $u=\sqrt{3}v$.

Comment: In general,$$\frac1a\arctan(t/a)=\int_0^t\frac1{u^2+a^2}\ du$$for $a>0$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Substitute $u=\sqrt{3}t$. $${\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{1}{\mathrm{u}^{2}+3}\,\mathrm{d}u=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}{\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{1}{t^2+1}\,\mathrm{d}t=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\arctan \left(t\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\arctan \left(\frac{u}{\sqrt{3}}\right)$$
Done! Now put back $u=e^x$ to get the answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can write:
$$\int \frac{1}{u^2+3}\ du= \int \frac{1}{3\left(\frac{u^2}{3}+1\right)}\ du= \frac{1}{3}\int \frac{1}{\left(\frac{u}{\sqrt3}\right)^2+1}\ du=\frac{1}{\sqrt3}\int \frac{\frac1{\sqrt3}}{\left(\frac{u}{\sqrt3}\right)^2+1}\ du= \\ =\frac{1}{\sqrt3}\arctan \left(\frac{u}{\sqrt{3}}\right)+C$$

without using a substitution.

Answer (score 1):

$\int \frac{1}{u^2+3}\ du= \frac{1}{3}\int \frac{1}{\left(\frac{u}{\sqrt3}\right)^2+1}\ du=\frac{1}{\sqrt3}\tan^{-1} \left(\frac{u}{\sqrt{3}}\right)+C$

Comment: No offense, Sagar, but this seems to be a carbon copy of what @flytothesurface wrote.